# How to make tiny_tds gem workable in Jruby 1.7.6 platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Tiny_tds gem contains native extensions which is not supporting in Jruby. By setting `JRUBY_OPTS to "--1.9 -Xcext.enabled=true"` in user variables also not made it work. Please advice how to make it work in `Jruby 1.7.6.`

Comment: @Pradeep, are you aware of any possible steps to solve my question

Comment: have you found solution to making tiny_tds work in Jruby? Having problems with what to do for jruby on rails + mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-ext are not supported by JRuby. they were working to some extend in older versions but the support was never complete (and was dropped) and its very likely `tiny_tds` uses pieces of the MRI-C API that are not implemented.

people usually use alternatives on JRuby (assuming the gem does not provide native version for C-Ruby as well as JRuby - which many do). for connecting to MS-SQL there's JDBC drivers which will work under Java. 
although the API is different than that of `tiny_tds` you can get emulate some of its pieces - depending how much of tiny_tds you really need, if its too much you should look into libraries such as `Sequel` or `ActiveRecord` which can work with MS-SQL using JDBC drivers.